# how to set content encoding gzip in tomcat

Tags: web-services, tomcat, caching

I am trying to speed up my website,

With first step i compressed static content like JS, CSS and Images with Tomcat.

Updated server.xml as

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" compression="on"
compressionMinSize="2048"
noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
compressableMimeType="text/css, text/javascript, application/x-javascript, application/javascript, text/html, text/plain, text/xml, application/xml, x-font/otf, application/x-font-woff, x-font/ttf, x-font/eot"/>
```

This worked fine for request header

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
```

But in response, there is no

```
content encoding: gzip
```

Can any one help me in this

i tried few links as

[Enable GZIP Compression In Tomcat](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/)

[gzip your Tomcat response](http://learningviacode.blogspot.in/2012/11/gzip-your-tomcat-response.html)

and change `compression="on"` to `compression="force"`

than response change to

`content encoding: gzip`

but is this a right way to get gzip response

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1):

In Tomcat 8.5 the right way to enable standard compression (gzip) is to add in server.xml file, under the catalina http connector those 2 attributes:

- useSendfile="false"
- compression="on"

following my connector example:

```
<Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" useSendfile="false"
           compression="on" compressionMinSize="1024" />
```

info: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html

Answer (score -1):

Its not the right way to force for compression. After configuring tomcat you have to handle it in your servlet depending upon whether client accepts compression or not.

You can make use of `accept-encoding` header to check for support of compression.
This [Link](http://pdf.coreservlets.com/HTTP-Request-Headers.pdf) has good explanation how to achieve this

Answer (score -1):

FYI it's not `compressableMimeType` it is spelled `compressibleMimeType` with an 'i' not an 'a'

Comment: Despite what the documentation says, the parameter is `compressableMimeType`. If you spell with `i` it throws an error in `catalina.out` that parameter is not found. Tested on Tomcat7 which was current at the time the question was asked